# The specified value cannot be parsed, or is out of range in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a form that will update a product's pricing when adding the unit amount of the product and
a price of the product, but when I type into one of my textboxes I end up getting this error

> The specified value "unit_product_1" cannot be parsed, or is out of range

I don't know what that means or how to solve it.

Here is my code

```
<template>
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>Unit</th>
                                                <th>Price</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>

                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr v-for="product in products">
                                                <td>{{ product['name'] }}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="product['unit']">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="product['price']">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    props: [],
    data(){
        return {
            products: [],
            unit_product_1: null,
            price_product_1: null,
        }
    },
    computed:{

    },
    methods: {
        getProducts(){
            axios.get(`/api/product/all`).then(response => {
               this.products = response.data.products;
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this. getProducts();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's not being used in the code shown

Answer (score 0):

```
unit_product_1: null,
price_product_1: null
```

You don't use them anywhere.
If you want to mutate your incoming products, you should make a new POST request and send the data back to the server. In this scenario you must know how the server waits to receive the data and send them back as requested.